# Maximize Div without moving in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to maximize a `div` to whole windows width and height (or another parent div) without moving the element in the DOM. Is this even possible only with CSS?

```
<div id="parent1" class="fullwidth"> 
    <div id="parent2" class="notfullwidth">
         <div style="position:absolute">mycontent</div><!-- make this full width of parent1/overlay parent1 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it could be achieved by positioning the `#parent1` `relative`ly and expanding the `absolute`ly positioned grand child by setting its `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` properties to `0`.

```css
#parent1 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: gold;
}

#parent2 {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.grand-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 30, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent1" class="fullwidth"> 
    <div id="parent2" class="notfullwidth">
         <div class="grand-child">mycontent</div><!-- make this full width of parent1/overlay parent1 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am new to code snippets. Where is the Full page button code?

Answer (score 0):

If the parent doesn't have a relative position, then the child can be expand to full width/height relative to window.

```
#mycontent {
 background-color: green;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
}
```

if the parent1 has a relative position, the the child would expand to the parent max width & max height.

```
#parent1 {
 position: relative;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
}
#mycontent {
 background-color: green;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
}
```